# Using Eval to Set AutoPostBack Property in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval, telerik-grid, itemtemplate

I am using a `RadGrid` from Telerik and trying to toggle a `RadioButtonList`'s `AutoPostBack` property based on a `CheckBox` elsewhere on the page.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rg" runat="server" Skin="Office2010Silver" GridLines="Both" OnNeedDataSource="rg_NeedDataSource"
                 OnItemDataBound="rg_ItemDataBound">
    <MasterTableView Width="100%" DataKeyNames="StudentID, Response, Tested">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="StudentName" HeaderText="Student Name" DataField="StudentName"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="StudentID" HeaderText="Student ID" DataField="StudentID"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Answer" HeaderText="Answer" DataField="Answer"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Response" HeaderText="Score" DataField="Response"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Score" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblScore" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblScore_IndexChanged" AutoPostBack='<%#Eval(chkAutoSave.Checked.ToString()) %>'></asp:RadioButtonList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

I get the error: `DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView'` does not contain a property with the name `True`. Is it possible to do it this way, or do I need to do this within `ItemDataBound`?

Comment: I am not familiar with the RadGrid however I have used Eval quite often with repeaters and it is always in the context of the data that is being bound to the repeater, which seems the same here.  It looks like it is trying to find what chkAutoSave.Checked.ToString() evaluates to, which is True, within the DataRowView that is being bound to the RadGrid.  Try just getting rid of the Eval statement.

<% chkAutoSave.Checked %>

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and used ItemDataBound and that works fine... but I'd be interested if someone has a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

first Give an Id to the Template Column

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Score" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ID="Score">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblScore" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblScore_IndexChanged" AutoPostBack='<%#Eval(chkAutoSave.Checked.ToString()) %>'></asp:RadioButtonList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

In Code Behind:

```
  protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
            {
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
                            {
    GridDataItem dataBoundItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
    Bool _boolChecked=Convert.ToBoolean(dataBoundItem["chkAutoSave.Checked"].toString());
              ((RadioButtonList )dataBoundItem["Score"].FindControl("rblScore")).AutoPostBack= _boolChecked;
    }
    }
```

Regards

Comment: Right, this is doing it with the ItemDataBound which I know works.